# Plone: How to get images in carousel to rotate automatically?

Tags: plone

I'm using a website that runs on Plone. On the homepage, the carousel has several images that you have to click the next number to see the next image. What I want though, is to get these images to rotate automatically after a certain number of seconds. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: What plugin/addon are you using for the carousel?

Comment: Hi, when I go to Site Setup >> Add-on Products, one of the items is "Carousel for Plone". Is that what you are referring to? Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @user2895209: Plone doesn't come with a Carousel by default, somebody has installed it, and we need to know it's name. It's something like "foo.bar.carousel" or "Products.Something" or similar. I would *guess* that you are using "Products.Carousel", but it's best to make sure first.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very helpful if you could mention current setting for the portlet you're using.

However most probably it is because you forgot to set a reasonable value for `Timer` field.  Check the settings for the carousel portlet and set the `Timer` to for example 5 and see what happens.